# Parent & child elements click event handling in Angular5

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular5

In Angular5,

I have the code like below.

```html
   <div (click)="abc()">
    some content
    <button (click)="xyz()">Click</button>
    </div>
```

Whenever I click on button,the two methods are calling.But i want to call a single method.it belongs to button click.

How to handle it in Angular5

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to [stop the propagation of the event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) in the xyz method:

thus in the template :

```
<div (click)="abc()">
    some content
    <button (click)="xyz($event)">Click</button>
</div>
```

In the component

```
xyz = function (event: Event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    ... // rest of the stuff 
}
```